# SSH into VM in private network not working

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I had created several VMs in GCP in a private network ie. With no Public IP Address associated with the instances. The SSH Button from the console was useable and I was able to SSH to any instance at that time.

The next week when I tried to SSH again, I was unable to click on SSH and it shows

[image: This instance does not have an external IP - Image]

I have not changed anything from my end. All infrastructure is managed by terraform only and no one has changed that.

Can it be due to any other API enabling/disabling? Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you

Comment: If you are sure no one has directly removed `external IP` then there is a good chance someone has interacted with the Compute Engine API and somehow tweaked the natIp. 

 Can you share all of your instances behaving the same or its just one?

Comment: All instances in the private subnet have the behavior.
I was able to fix the issue by removing and adding the permission for my user again.
I did try that earlier as well, but it worked only the second time.

Comment: Did you check the Project Wise IAM Permissions? What permissions do you have on accessing the VMs

Answer (score 1):

One thing that could be preventing you from establish a ssh connection to your VM is the IAM permissions. If your IAM permissions have been edited recently,it could be an explanation of why the ssh is disabled. Please, check if you have a [compute instance admin role](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ssh-in-browser#connecting_to_a_linux_vm_instance) on your VMs.

You can also verify that the changes have been applied correctly by using the following command on the GCP shell:

```
gcloud policy-troubleshoot iam resource --principal-email=email \
    --permission=permission
```

This should give you further detail on your IAM settings for a given user, and maybe give you a clue about what may be causing you the ssh issue.

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be an IAM permission issue of some sort.
I removed and added the permission for my user again and it worked the second time only.
Really Weird issue though.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I've edited the comment, because I found a GCP command to troubleshoot the IAM policy in a project. Please, check if the changes have been properly made there...and comment here the results the shell gives you back.